# How to display a report in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, custom-reports

I need to display a report in a Lightning Component. But I am not able to see any information related to it.

I need to display a report as it is.

Previously, we used to write VF page code and use "iframe" tag. But, this also doesn't work now.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

IFrame will work on lightning component as well
or else you can try lightning:container which behaves like Iframe only.
refer the below link

[Lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_container.htm)

Comment: It is not working using "Lightning:container". It is not displaying anything.